# PySpark: Use value in column dynamically to reference another column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with multiple prices per customer and would like to fetch the relevant price depending on the value in the column. Such that my dataframe is as follows:

| customer | price_point | price_a | price_b | price_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | price_b | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| B | price_a | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| C | price_c | 1 | 2 | 2 |

and I would expect something like the following:

```
customers = customers.withColumn("final_price", col(col("price_point")))
```

To return:

| customer | price_point | price_a | price_b | price_c | final_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | price_b | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| B | price_a | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| C | price_c | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

However, I get an error that the column is not iterable. Is it possible in Spark to use the value of a column dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a UDF as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

@F.udf(T.IntegerType())
def get_price(price_point, price_a, price_b, price_c):
    
    prices = {
        "price_a": price_a, 
        "price_b": price_b, 
        "price_c": price_c
    }
    
    return prices.get(price_point)

(
    df.withColumn(
        "final_price", 
        get_price("price_point", "price_a", "price_b", "price_c")
    )
    .show()
)
```

Also pay attention to the `@F.udf(T.IntegerType())` output signature. If your price is float, it should be `@F.udf(T.FloatType())`, etc.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are only limited price column then a case when should work fine

```
customers.withColumn("final_price",expr("case when price_point='price_a' then price_a when price_point='price_b' then price_b else price_c end"))
```